# Make a script that starts and shutdown both redis and sidekiq

Tags: bash, redis, sidekiq

I'm fairly new to Bash, redis and linux in general and I'm having trouble with creating a script. This is also my first question, I hope it is not a duplicate.

So here's the problem, I'm creating a simple application in ruby for educational purposes, but the feature I'm trying to implement uses redis and sidekiq. What I want to do is to create an executable script (I named it server) that initiates the redis server, initiates the redis, but it should also shutdown redis after the user finalizes the sidekiq.

This is what I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

set -e

redis-server --daemonize yes

bundle exec sidekiq -r ./a/sample/path/worker.rb

redis-cli shutdown # this is not working, I want to execute this after shutting sidekiq down...
```

When I run the fourth line, it starts the little Sidekiq "welcome page" and I can't to anything until I shut it down with `Control + C`. I assumed that after shutting it with this command, it would continue with the script I wrote, which would be the `redis-cli shutdown` command.
But it does not. When I `Control + C` the sidekiq, it simply goes back to the command line.

Is there anyone familiar with these concepts that could help me? I wanted a script that would also shutdown redis after I'm done with sidekiq.

Thanks!

Comment: I would look into docker and docker-compose for this

Comment: does adding a `&` at the end of the sidekiq line help? Also, `set -e` might be a premature optimization, do you know what it does? do you really want the script to stop processing if an error is encountered? If you are running this just from command line, then that is probably ok, but if you make this an automatic process you'll need to handle the error better (for your future learning ;-) ). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using Foreman?

http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html

https://github.com/ddollar/foreman